# Using unzip() in R: how to deal with duplicate file names?

Tags: r, unzip

I have a large number of nested directories with .ZIP files containing .CSV files that I want to loop through in R, extract the contents using unzip(), and then read the csv files into R.

However, there are many cases (numbering thousands of files) where there are multiple .zip files in the same directory containing .csv files with identical file names. If I set the overwrite=FALSE argument in unzip(), it ignores all duplicated names after the first. What I want is for it to extract all files but add some suffix to the file name that will allow the duplicated files to be extracted to the same directory, so that I do not have to create even more nested subdirectories to hold the files.

Example:

> Directory ~/zippedfiles contains:
>
> archive1.zip (consists of foo.csv, bar.csv), archive2.zip (foo.csv, blah.csv)

Run the following:

```
unzip('~/zippedfiles/archive1.zip', exdir='~/zippedfiles', overwrite=FALSE)
unzip('~/zippedfiles/archive2.zip', exdir='~/zippedfiles', overwrite=FALSE)
```

The result is

- bar.csv
- blah.csv
- foo.csv

The desired result is

- bar.csv
- blah.csv
- foo.csv
- foo(1).csv

Comment: You can use `unzip("a.zip",list=T)` to get the names of the files in the zip file and `list.files(path=".",include.dir=F)` to get the names of the files in the current directory. Then rename what you have to prior to extracting the files.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than renaming the duplicate file names, why not keep them unique by assigning a separate folder for each unzip action (just like your OS probably would). This way you don't have to worry about changing file names, and you end up with a single list referencing all unzipped folders:

```
setwd( '~/zippedfiles' )

# get a list of ".zip" files
ziplist <- list.files( pattern = ".zip" )

# start a fresh vector to fill
unzippedlist <- vector( mode = "character", length = 0L )

# for every ".zip" file we found...
for( zipfile in ziplist ) {

    # decide on a name for an output folder
    outfolder <- gsub( ".zip", "", zipfile )

    # create the output folder
    dir.create( outfolder )

    # unzip into the new output folder
    unzip( 'zipfile', exdir = outfolder, overwrite=FALSE )

    # get a list of files just unzipped
    newunzipped <- list.files( path = outfolder, full.names = T )

    # add that new list of files to the complete list
    unzippedlist <- c( unzippedlist, newunzipped )
}
```

The vector `unzippedlist` should contain all of your unzipped files, with every one being unique, not necessarily by file name, but by a combination of directory *and* filename. So you can pass it as a vector to capture all of your files.

Comment: Great workaround but is it really true that there is no option to automatically rename files?

Comment: I doubt it. That's more a system level function, so if you really wanted to do it from within R, you'd probably need to look at a function like system() as suggested by @Robin K. But then you're not really coding in R any more.

Comment: You could use a combination of `make.unique` to create unique names for the vector, then `file.rename` to apply the new name to those files that need it, then `file.copy` and `file.remove` to move them into one folder (I don't know of a `file.move` function). It becomes very convoluted obviously, for a function that your OS will usually do routinely (hence the `system` suggestions).

Answer (score 0):

A solution for you might be to use system()/system2() and then use one of the countless unix methods to archieve that.